# node-sass не устанавливается

Tags: node.js, sass, webpack

Несмотря на все ухищрения не устанавливается node-sass. sass-loader для webpack установился нормально (есть в package.json), а модуль node-sass устанавливается (видно появляется соответствующая папка в  node-modules, IDE Sublime Text), потом выдается ошибка и папка исчезает.

Ошибка такая

```
failed at the node-sass@3.4.2 postinstall
node scripts/build.js

Exit status 3221225477
```

Я все перепробовала: создавала карту в `webpack.config.js`

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: 'style!css!sass?sourceMap'
}
```

В `loader.js` заменила строчку

```
if(map && typeof map !== "string") {
    map = JSON.stringify(map);
    }
```

Ничего не работает! Или на windows XP в принципе не устанавливается этот модуль ( хотя все остальные модули справно работают)?

Answer (score 4):

Вот и нашла ответ на свой вопрос. На XP есть проблема со входом в библиотеку msvcrt.dll для Ruby. Хотя похожие проблемы с установкой node-sass есть и на 10 версии OS. На старых версиях проблема решается установкой своей среды разработки. Подробности здесь:

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/issues/239

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit#building-the-devkit

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/